# Passing a Fantom type literal

Tags: types, casting, fantom

I'm trying to dynamically cast an object in Fantom to the desired type chosen at runtime.

```
Type type := Int#
Obj n := 1 as Obj
echo((n as type).toStr)
```

This is a simplified example. I want to pass the type to a class and have it initialised when run.

Comment: What is your use-case? this is not possible, but there may be a better solution to your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple answer would be to just use a [dynamic invoke](http://fantom.org/doc/docLang/Methods.html#dynamicInvoke), that is, use `->` instead of `.`. If you know the method exists, then you don't even need to know the type:

```
n := (Obj) 1
echo( n->toStr() )
```

But more generally, you can't *dynamically cast* as you suggested. For if you don't know what `type` is at compile time, then how is the compiler supposed to know!?

Usually `n` would implement a method that's defined on a parent supertype, you would then cast `n` to that that supertype and call the method normally:

```
myObj := ...
n := (Supertype) myObj
n.myMethod()
```

But if there is no common parent type, then *dynamic invoke* is the way to go.

...or use reflection! It's a doddle in [Fantom](http://fantom-lang.org/):

```
n := (Obj) 1
method := n.typeof.method("toStr")
echo( method.callOn(n, null) )
```